# addClass to parent(LI)

Tags: jquery, addclass

I have an element "A", when I click on it, I want to change parent element's (`LI`) class to `selected`, but nothing changes...

```
$(".filters-list li a").click(function () {
    $(".filters-list li").removeClass("selected");
    $(this).parent('li').addClass('selected'); // I also tried .parent().addClass
});
```

Then I tried this code:

```
$(".filters-list li a").click(function () {
    $(".filters-list li").removeClass("selected");
    $(this).parent().get(0).addClass('selected'); // IE reports something like this: Object doesn't support addClass...
});
```

When I tried to define `LI` with this code, it just reported me `[Object HTMLLIElement]`:

```
alert($(this).parent().get(0));
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: could it be the single quotes and double quotes around the  class selected?

Comment: What does the HTML look like?

Comment: `$(this).parent().get(0)` is a raw DOM object, not a jQuery object. That's why it says "Object doesn't support addClass". You can convert it to a jQuery object by putting a `$()` round it. (But if you fix this I don't think it will be any better than the first attempt, so you still have to find another bug anyway.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try

```
$(".filters-list li a").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".filters-list li").removeClass("selected");
    $(this).closest('li').addClass('selected'); // I also tried .parent().addClass
});
```

[**.closest()**](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) will get the first element that matches the selector.

Comment: @po4teda, can you make a demo in a jsfiddle. What happens when you click the a element? load a new page?

Comment: After 3 days of desperation looking for answer of my question about "HOW TO GET THE PARENT AND ADD CLASS TO IT"
Then I found this answer, 
you sir deserve my upvote

Answer (score 2):

I made a sample for you:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://codeorigin.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .selected {font-weight:bold}
    </style>
    <ul class="filters-list">
        <li class="selected"><a href="#section1">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section2">Gallery Photos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section3">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("click",".filters-list li a", function () {
        $(".filters-list li").removeClass("selected");
        $(this).parent().addClass("selected");
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
$(this).parents("li:first").addClass('selected');
```

it could be that you are not selecting the target parent

Comment: Consider expanding your answer to explain to the asker why this achieves the desired result, possibly linking to documentation. As is, this is only marginally useful.