# Add class to upper li when underlaying input is checked

Tags: jquery, html, class

I use a list with `<li>` elements, where I want to add a class to the li when the input inside the `<li>` is checked.

How can I achieve that?

HTML:

```
    <dl class="sp-methods" id="checkout-payment-method-load">
    <?php foreach ($methods as $_method):
        $_code = $_method->getCode();
?>
    <li class="formListBlock payment_<?php echo $_code ?>">
    <?php if(!$oneMethod): ?>
     <label for="p_method_<?php echo $_code ?>">
        <input id="p_method_<?php echo $_code ?>" value="<?php echo $_code ?>" type="radio" name="payment[method]" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_method->getTitle()) ?>" onclick="payment.switchMethod('<?php echo $_code ?>')"<?php if($this->getSelectedMethodCode()==$_code): ?> checked="checked"<?php elseif($_code == $this->__('ops_iDeal')): ?>checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> class="radio" />
        <p class="payment-title"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getMethodTitle($_method)) ?> <?php echo $this->getMethodLabelAfterHtml($_method) ?></p>
    <?php else: ?>
        <span class="no-display"><input id="p_method_<?php echo $_code ?>" value="<?php echo $_code ?>" type="radio" name="payment[method]" checked="checked" class="radio" /></span>
        <?php $oneMethod = $_code; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ($html = $this->getPaymentMethodFormHtml($_method)): ?>
    <span class="payment_icon_<?php echo $_code ?>"></span>
    <span class="gratis">TEXT</span>
    <span class="paypal"> TEXT </span>
    </label>
    <div class="formListBlock-selector payment_<?php echo $_code ?>">
        <?php echo $html; ?>
    </div>
    </li>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach;
    </dl>
```

jQuery:

```
$('input:radio').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $('li.formListBlock').addClass("menuitemshow");
    } else {
        $('li.formListBlock').removeClass("menuitemshow");
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you post your jQuery code? In short, you need a click event hooked up to your input. And then find the parent li and set the class. Look in the jQuery API at `.on()`, `.parent()`. http://api.jquery.com/ Possible duplicate.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19202076/addclass-to-parentli

Comment: @Huelfe I tried the code above, but that does not seem to work well.

Comment: @KrisHollenbeck I tried the code above, but that does not seem to work well.

Comment: Is the input dynamically added to the DOM?

Comment: @KrisHollenbeck No it is not, I guess that's the problem. Can you give me a example how to get it right? I updated my question with the dynamic code.

Comment: Well you don't have a checkbox. You are using a radio button.

Comment: @Huelfe Thanks! Sorry, I changed it already, but that also does not seem to work.

Comment: [This fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/406hqfwe/) works.

Comment: @Huelfe Thanks, the only problem is that the code is dynamic. So that does not work with my code, how can I make it work with my dynamic code?

Comment: Ok then you have to use [this code](https://jsfiddle.net/406hqfwe/1/).

Comment: @Huelfe Thanks! But when I try your code on my site, it does not work. See my dynamic code in the question. Am I missing something?

Comment: Oh I thought dynamic like ajax. Does [this](https://jsfiddle.net/406hqfwe/2/) work?

Comment: @Huelfe No, that does also not work.

Comment: But this should really work. What problem do you have? What is `not working`?

Comment: @Huelfe It is not adding the class to the specific li. I can not find why, but is not added.

Comment: But you are now using `<input type="checkbox" />` instead of `radio`?

Comment: @Huelfe Thanks! No am not, because I can not change that. Can I change your code and use the radio button instead? Because I need the radio button for this.

Comment: You have only one radio option. This is not really user friendly. But if you only have the radio field -  use [this code](https://jsfiddle.net/406hqfwe/5/).

Comment: @Huelfe Thanks! That almost works, but it does add the class only. When switching to another radio button, it does not remove the class.

Comment: Then you have to remove that class. :) Like this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/406hqfwe/6/).

Comment: @Huelfe Thanks!! Works perfectly. If you add an anwser, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `$("#ul_id [name='name']")` to select all inputs with specific name and `.closest("li")` to get closest `<li>` tag.

See this example

```js
$("#checkout-payment-method-load [name='payment[method]']").change(function() {
$("#checkout-payment-method-load [name='payment[method]']").each(function(){
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $(this).closest("li").addClass("menuitemshow");
  } else {
    $(this).closest("li").removeClass("menuitemshow");
  }
});
});
```

```css
.menuitemshow {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="sp-methods" id="checkout-payment-method-load">
  <li class="formListBlock payment_ops_cc">
    <label for="p_method_ops_cc">
      <input id="p_method_ops_cc" value="ops_cc" type="radio" name="payment[method]" title="Creditcard" onclick="/*payment.switchMethod('ops_cc')*/" class="radio validation-passed" autocomplete="off">
      <p class="payment-title">Creditcard</p>
      <span class="payment_icon_ops_cc"></span>
      <span class="gratis">Text</span>
      <span class="paypal">Text</span>
    </label>
  </li>

  <li class="formListBlock payment_ops_cc">
    <label for="p_method_ops_cc">
      <input id="p_method_ops_cc2" value="ops_cc" type="radio" name="payment[method]" title="Creditcard" onclick="/*payment.switchMethod('ops_cc')*/" class="radio validation-passed" autocomplete="off">
      <p class="payment-title">Creditcard</p>
      <span class="payment_icon_ops_cc"></span>
      <span class="gratis">Text</span>
      <span class="paypal">Text</span>
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks! But when I try your code on my site, it does not work. See my dynamic code in the question. Am I missing something?

Comment: i see you have alot of `echo` hasn't end with simi-column `echo $_code;`

Comment: check final html source that PHP echo and also see what errors console says.